# Click a Windows pop up

Tags: c#, windows, selenium

I am performing UI automation on a web application using Selenium. There is this one instance where I might encounter a windows pop up and I am not able to close it using Selenium ( which is not possible, anyways). I am looking for a work around to click OK button on this windows pop up.Since this task cannot be performed with Selenium, I am open to any tool/coding language that automates this process.

Comment: You can use `Autoit`

Comment: @ssujaykodamala Update the question with relevant HTML, code trials and error encountered.

Comment: What kind of "windows pop up"?